# How do we express naturally a thing that is used not a clean one?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

There are 2 cloths on the table: one is clean and one is used.

The used one is **not too dirty** as I have used it to wipe his hand. I want to damp a cloth and wipe my counter with it. So, it is unnecessary to use the clean cloth.

So, I am standing in the kitchen and ask my daughter "*could you go get the used cloth on the table for me, not the clean one?*".

**Do we have common term to express a thing that is used but not too dirty like the cloth I mentioned above?**

Comment: It looks like you just found it - "the used cloth" works fine in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, 'used' is probably the best word. It doesn't inherently mean that something is dirty. People buy 'used' goods all the time such as used cars, used furniture etc, so your suggestion of "*fetch me the used cloth*" seems fine.

Some people in the UK say that things like cloths are "in use" when they have already begun to be used, but are still within their usable cycle before either being disposed of or being cleaned for re-use.

"Soiled" is an adjective that can mean dirtied through expected use, but is often used in connection with unsanitary things like diapers and bandages, so probably wouldn't fit your context.